# How to check JSON string on contains field AND like value?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSON:

```
[{"name": "Criss", "idNumber": "2177"}, {"name": "Kate", "idNumber": "6234"}]
[{"name": "Alex"}, {"name": "Paul"}]
[{"name": "Emma", "idNumber": "2056"}, {"name": "Isabella", "idNumber": "8832"}]
[{"name": "Olivia", "idNumber": "2163"}, {"name": "Greck", "idNumber": "8585"}]
```

I need to find all lines, which contains field **idNumber** and also value must be `like '21%'`

I use `@>` operator for check on contains. But how check on `LIKE`?

Expected result:

```
[{"name": "Criss", "idNumber": "2177"}, {"name": "Kate", "idNumber": "6234"}]
[{"name": "Olivia", "idNumber": "2163"}, {"name": "Greck", "idNumber": "8585"}]
```

Comment: Do you what to achieve this using java/sql ?

Comment: Why so many tags, is it sql or java code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: it`s SQL. Without Java code

Comment: select json_field
from table
where json_field @> '[{"idNumber" : "2177"}]'

Comment: But I need also use LIKE operator on this

Comment: This would be so much simpler with a properly normalized model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest your array in order to be able to use an operator on each element in there.

This can be done in a co-related subquery:

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t1.d) as x(e)
              where x.e ->> 'idNumber' like '21%');
```

There is no need to test for the presence of the key `idNumber` separately as the `->>` will return `null` if the key isn't there.

Online example: https://rextester.com/KZY46113